# Embed grafana dashboard area only

Tags: iframe, grafana, dashboard

I would like to embed grafana dashboard to an angular application. Tried dashboard share and panel share. It gives a URL to be added in an iframe. But it displays all the editable options too. I would like only panel area to be visible (only the area inside the green rectangle in the screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Kiosk mode.

Manually, you can enable it by clicking on the icon in the upper right corner (on hover: *cycle view mode*).

For using it when embedding a dashboard, you can enable it by adding `kiosk` to the URL parameters. Example: `https://www.your-grafana-instance.com/d/dashboard-id/dashboard-name?orgId=1&kiosk`